# The norm of the principal series intertwining operator for $\operatorname{GL}_2$

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, reductive-groups, langlands-conjectures, induced-representations

Is there a known bound on the norm of the standard intertwining operator for the principal series of $G = \operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb Q_p)$?

**Background:**
For a character $\chi = (\chi_1,\chi_2)$ of the standard torus $T$ in $G$, extended to a character of the standard Borel subgroup $B = TU$ we can define the induced representation $I(\chi) = \operatorname{Ind}_B^G \chi$ to be the Banach space of all measurable functions $f: G \rightarrow \mathbb C$ satisfying $f(tng) = \chi(t)\delta_B^{1/2}(t)f(g)$ and the norm condition
$$\lVert f\rVert^2 = \int\limits_K \lvert f(k)\rvert^2 dk < \infty$$
where $K = \operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb Z_p)$ (usually, one works with the subspace $I(\chi)^{\infty}$ of locally constant functions in $I(\chi)$).  If $w = \begin{pmatrix} & 1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}$, the standard intertwining operator $M: I(\chi) \rightarrow I(w(\chi))$ is densely defined on $I(\chi)^{\infty}$ by
$$Mf(g) = \int\limits_N f(wng)dn.$$
This converges for $\sigma = \operatorname{Re}(\chi_1\chi_2^{-1}) > 0$, but can be extended to make sense for most $\chi_1$, $\chi_2$ by a process of analytic continuation.

**What I want to do**:

I want to compute, or get an upper bound on, the norm $\lVert M\rVert = \sup\limits_{\lVert f\rVert=1} \lVert Mf\rVert$.  Actually, I'm trying to show that the *global* intertwining operator for $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb A_{\mathbb Q})$, densely defined as a product of local intertwining operators, is a bounded linear operator.  The norm of the global intertwining operator should be a convergent product of the norms of the local operators.

**Computations for $\lVert{-}\rVert_1$**:

If we use the $1$-norm instead of the $2$-norm, I can get an estimate for $\lVert M\rVert_1$.  There may be a way to modify these calculations for the $2$-norm, but I haven't been able to do it.  For $f$ locally constant,
\begin{gather*}
\lVert Mf\rVert = \int\limits_K  \lvert Mf(k)\rvert dk \leq \int\limits_K \int\limits_N \lvert f(wnk)\rvert dn\,dk= \int\limits_{N(\mathbb Z_p)} \int\limits_K \lvert f(wnk)\rvert dk\,dn + \int\limits_{n \not\in N(\mathbb Z_p)} \int\limits_K \lvert f(wnk)\rvert dk\,dn \\
=\int\limits_{N(\mathbb Z_p)} \int\limits_K \lvert f(k)\rvert dk\,dn + \int\limits_{x \in \mathbb Q_p - \mathbb Z_p} \int\limits_K \left\lvert f(w \begin{pmatrix} 1 & x \\ & 1 \end{pmatrix}k)\right\rvert dk\,dx = \lVert f\rVert_1 + \int\limits_{x \in \mathbb Q_p - \mathbb Z_p} \int\limits_K \left\lvert f(w \begin{pmatrix} 1 & x \\ & 1 \end{pmatrix}k)\right\rvert dk\,dx.
\end{gather*}
This last integral is
\begin{gather*}
\int\limits_{x \in \mathbb Q_p - \mathbb Z_p} \int\limits_K \left\lvert f( \begin{pmatrix} -x^{-1} & 1 \\ & -x\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ x^{-1} & 1 \end{pmatrix} k)\right\rvert dk\,dx = \int\limits_{x \in \mathbb Q_p - \mathbb Z_p} \int\limits_K \lvert x\rvert^{-\sigma} \lvert f(k)\rvert dk\,d^{\ast}x = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \lVert f\rVert_1 \int\limits_{\lvert x\rvert = p^k} \lvert x\rvert^{-\sigma}d^{\ast}x \\
= \lVert f\rVert_1 \operatorname{Vol}(\mathbb Z_p^{\ast}) \frac{p^{-\sigma}}{1- p^{-\sigma}}.
\end{gather*}

So we see that for $\sigma = \operatorname{Re}(\chi_1\chi_2^{-1}) > 0$, the $1$-norm $\lVert M\rVert_1$ is bounded by $1 + \operatorname{Vol}(\mathbb Z_p^{\ast}) \frac{p^{-\sigma}}{1- p^{-\sigma}}$.

Comment: I did some tidying in the TeX.  At one point, you said that you're bounding $\lVert f\rVert_1$ when I'm pretty sure you're bounding $\lVert M\rVert_1$.  Later, you say you've accomplished a bound on $\lVert M f\rVert_1$, which is true, but the point seemed to be the resulting bound on $\lVert M\rVert_1$.  I changed both accordingly.

Comment: Why doesn't the same argument give you $\lVert M\rVert_2^2 \le 1 + \operatorname{Vol}(\mathbb Z_p^\times)\frac{p^{-2\sigma}}{1 - p^{-2\sigma}}$?

Comment: The integrand must be squared and that seems to disrupt things considerably

Comment: Ah, right, the very first integral is $\int_K \left(\int_N \cdots\right)^2$.  I wasn't paying attention to where that square went.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a bound on $\|M\|_1$, you get by duality a bound on $\|M\|_\infty$
and then you get a bound on $\|M\|_p$ for every $1\leq p\leq\infty$
by the [Riesz–Thorin theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Thorin_theorem).